# Cambiar colores del menú, Navigation Drawer; Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, menú

no he podido cambiar el color de la etiqueta de la secciones que agrupan los menús, como muestro en la imagen, pude cambiar el fondo y el color de los textos que ahora son blancos, pero en el item: Plataformas, deja el color que trae por defecto.

Los menus a los que les pude cambiar el color, lo hice en el activity_main, donde está contenido el fragment activity_main_drawer: con la siguiente etiqueta: app:itemTextColor="@color/NavText, sin embargo no cambia el color del item con nombre Plataformas.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@mipmap/portal"
        android:title="Portal"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@mipmap/noticias"
        android:title="Noticias" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@mipmap/biblioteca"
        android:title="Biblioteca" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@mipmap/eduvirtual"
        android:title="EduVirtual" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_dir"
        android:icon="@mipmap/directorio"
        android:title="Directorio" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_rutas"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ubicacion"
        android:title="Rutas" />
</group>

<item

    android:title="Plataformas">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_siga"
            android:icon="@mipmap/siga"
            android:title="Siga" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_moodle"
            android:icon="@mipmap/moodle"
            android:title="Moodle" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `OnCreate` de tu activity

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
//este es el que cambia el color de fondo 
navigationView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorfondo));
```

Comment: Hola rolando, te invito a leer [answer]

Answer (score 0):

```
//Para cambiar el color del texto del item de un menu.
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)));
//Para cambiar el color del icono del item de un menu.
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)));
```